# iOS, Core Data: Faulting NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data

```
case 0:
        {
            NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Grade"];
            NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"abbr==%@",@"UNDEF"];
            [request setPredicate:predicate];
            NSArray *result=[_context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
            Grade *grade=[result lastObject];
            duplicate.grade=grade;
            break;
        }
```

...

```
[self backgroundSaveContext];
```

Very simple question. What happens to retrieved object after the 'case' is done? Should I fault the object or ARC will manage it? This code executes not in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC does not manage faulting of managed objects.
You are setting `duplicate.grade` to the object retrieved from your fetch. If that is a strong reference, the managed object will be retained strongly - but this does not affect firing faults. It's only when you access a property of that object that a fault will fire.

When you fetch a managed object from a store using the default fetch request options, the managed object is unrealized - the properties do not have data attached to them. This is the faulted state. It's when you access a managed object property that Core Data "fires the fault" - it goes back to the store to get the property values and populates the managed object with those values. The property accessor method on the managed object calls `willAccessValueForKey:` which will realize (fire) the fault.

Comment: 'ARC does not manage faulting of managed objects' +1 for this.

Comment: 'It's only when you access a property of that object that a fault will fire'. Please explain me this part.